# assign multiple values to variables in a subclass of the same class

Tags: python, class, constructor

Open to suggestions for a better title...

If I remember this correctly, in Visual Basic you could assign multiple variables in a tree of some object with a 'with' constructor like this

`With Foo_Object.Foo_method
       .Bar_var1='foo'
       .Bar_var2='bar'
End With`

Is there a similar construct in Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a construct like this in Python.